# Get multiple regression coefficient values calculated by resampling

Tags: r, loops, regression, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I am calculating the coefficients of multiple linear models using resampling. Before I was using the `boot` function, but in the future need to include new statistics in the analysis so I think this way is better. A replicable example:

```
iris <- iris[,1:4]

nboots <- 100
ncol = ncol(iris)
boot.r.squared <- numeric(nboots)      
boot.p_model <- numeric(nboots)
boot.coef_p <- numeric(nboots)
boot.coef_estimate <- matrix(nrow= nboots,ncol=ncol)
boot.coef_error <- matrix(nrow= nboots,ncol=ncol)
boot.coef_t <- matrix(nrow= nboots,ncol=ncol)
boot.coef_p <- matrix(nrow= nboots,ncol=ncol)

for(i in 1:nboots){
  boot.samp <- iris[sample(nrow(iris),size = 100, replace = TRUE,), ] 
  model <- lm(boot.samp$Sepal.Length ~ .,boot.samp)
  model.sum <- summary(model)

  boot.r.squared[i] <- model.sum$r.squared
  stat <- model.sum$fstatistic
  boot.p_model[i] <- pf(stat[1], stat[2], stat[3], lower.tail = FALSE)

  boot.coef_estimate[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model$coefficients[1]
  boot.coef_error[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model$coefficients[2]
  boot.coef_t[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model$coefficients[3]
  boot.coef_p[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model$coefficients[4] 
}
```

But I can't correctly save the coefficients in the form of a matrix. I would like to save 4 matrices containing in each: parameter, the error, statistic t and p value.

With this code all columns are the same. I tried put [,1] to save the first column, but this error happens.  How can i fix this error?

> Error in model $ coefficients [, 1]: incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me without errors. You probably experimented with different numbers of repetitions and forgot to update the sizes of the empty objects you define before the loop, since I could reprocude your error when I changed to `nboots <- 1000`.

You could do that without a `for` loop and use `replicate()` instead (which is basically a wrapper for `lapply()`). The advantage is that it might be a little more straightforward and you won't need to define the empty objects beforehand.

The procedure is, *first*, to define a bootstrap function, say `bootFun()`, *second*, the actual bootstrap using `replicate()` which yields an array, and finally *third*, to process the data in the array into the desired matrices.

```
# Step 1 bootstrap function
bootFun <- function(X) {
  fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data=X)
  s <- summary(fit)
  r2 <- s$r.squared
  f <- s$fstatistic
  p.f <- pf(f[1], f[2], f[3], lower.tail = FALSE)
  ms <- s$coefficients
  return(cbind(ms, r2, p.f))
}

# Step 2 bootstrap
nboots <- 1e2
set.seed(42)  # for sake of reproducibility
A <- replicate(nboots, bootFun(iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), size=nrow(iris), replace=TRUE), ]))
# Note: I used here `size=nrow(iris)`, but you also could use size=100 if this is your method

# Step 3 process array ("de-transpose" and transform to list)
Ap <- aperm(A, c(3, 1, 2))  # aperm() is similar to t() for matrices
Aps <- asplit(Ap, 3)  # split the array into a handy list

# or in one step
Aps <- asplit(aperm(A, c(3, 1, 2)), 3)
```

## Result

Now you have a list containing all the matrices, look at the names of the list objects.

```
names(Aps)
# [1] "Estimate"   "Std. Error" "t value"    "Pr(>|t|)"   "r2"         "p.f"
```

So, if we e.g. want the matrix of our estimates, we simply do:

```
estimates <- Aps$Estimate

estimates[1:3, ]
#      (Intercept) Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# [1,]    1.353531   0.7655760    0.8322749  -0.7775090
# [2,]    1.777431   0.6653308    0.7353491  -0.6024095
# [3,]    2.029428   0.5825554    0.6941457  -0.4795787
```

Note, that the *F*-statistics and the *R<sup>2</sup>* are also matrices and duplicated in each row for every coefficient. Since you only need one, just extract e.g. the first column:

```
Aps$p.f[1:3, ]
#       (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width
# [1,] 2.759019e-65 2.759019e-65 2.759019e-65 2.759019e-65
# [2,] 5.451912e-66 5.451912e-66 5.451912e-66 5.451912e-66
# [3,] 3.288712e-54 3.288712e-54 3.288712e-54 3.288712e-54

Aps$p.f[1:3, 1]
# [1] 2.759019e-65 5.451912e-66 3.288712e-54
```

## Benchmark

The speed of both approaches is practically the same with a small advantage for `replicate()`. Here a benchmark comparing both methods where I used `nboot=1,000` replications.

```
# Unit: seconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   forloop 2.215259 2.235797 2.332234 2.381035 2.401933 2.700622   100   a
# replicate 2.218291 2.240570 2.313526 2.257905 2.400532 2.601958   100   a
```

Comment: Thank you! In its way the results got much better, now things are able to compute other statistics. I did not know aperm, I will research this function because it makes things much better.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your original code, you mixed up model and model.sum. You need to get the coefficients of summary(model) when you slot in coefficients, error, etc.

See below:

```
for(i in 1:nboots){
  boot.samp <- iris[sample(nrow(iris),size = 100, replace = TRUE,), ] 
  model <- lm(boot.samp$Sepal.Length ~ .,boot.samp)
  model.sum <- summary(model)

  boot.r.squared[i] <- model.sum$r.squared
  stat <- model.sum$fstatistic
  boot.p_model[i] <- pf(stat[1], stat[2], stat[3], lower.tail = FALSE)

  # this is the part where you need to use model.sum
  boot.coef_estimate[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model.sum$coefficients[,1]
  boot.coef_error[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model.sum$coefficients[,2]
  boot.coef_t[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model.sum$coefficients[,3]
  boot.coef_p[i, 1:length(model$coefficients)] <- model.sum$coefficients[,4] 
}
```

As a side comment,you want to know how variable is the estimate of the coefficient using boot. For the other statistics like r-square, p-value, interpreting these after bootstrap, is not so useful. So think about what you want to know from the bootstrap.

Also check out @jay.sf's answer, it's a much cleaner way to wrap your calculation functions..

Comment: You're right, the bootstrap for these coefficients alone doesn't add much from a statistical point of view. I will compare them to the initial statistic and get the value of p